# Nginx: What are the formats that access_log supports?

Tags: nginx, server, format, access-log

I am searching that. I saw that some of them are main or combined, but I want to know the complete ist of them, if it is possible. I visit webs like http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#access_log and http://hb.321key.org/hb/nginx-1.3.8/03A6EA3ED31C437BB3DF5902E32F2E68/504FEDDC2B.htm, but as I said, there is not a list of formats in them.

So if someone knows, please share the information. I will try to search for the explanation of each of them after that, thanks.

Comment: AFAIK `combined` is the only predefined format. All other formats are created using the `log_format` directive (in the same document you referenced in your question).

Comment: But I don't see "main", for example, and in other url, in https://serverfault.com/questions/768314/how-to-properly-set-up-access-log-for-nginx-cache I see "microcache". I don't see them in the web I have shared. Which is the origin of them?